# Use MS formats by default in LibreOffice

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, libreoffice

Can I (and if so, how?) set up LibreOffice to use the newer style MS Office formats by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the  *Tools* menu, select *Options*.  Under *Load/Save* on the list of property pages on the left of the *Settings* window, select *General*.  At the bottom of that property page, there are two drop down boxes, one labeled *Document type* and the other labeled *Always save as*.  These let you change the default save format for each type of document LibreOffice or OpenOffice supports.

Usually, *Text document* is selected first in the left box so, in the right box, select *Microsoft Word 2007 XML*.  Then, select *Spreadsheet* in the left box, and select *Microsoft Excel 2007 XML*.  Repeat for all the different document types you wish to save by default in Microsoft Office Open XML formats.